# ControlValueAccessor: registerOnChange() is never called

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an Angular 7 app that uses the `ControlValueAccessor` interface to make my control play well with Reactive Forms. Unfortunately, the `registerOnChange()` is never being called, so I cannot 'watch' my control's value.

The relevant source of my control looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wp-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './date-picker.component.scss' ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (date: Date) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(date: Date): void {
    if (date) {
      date = new Date(date);
      this.day = date.getDate();
      this.month = date.getMonth();
      this.year = date.getFullYear();
    }
  }

  get value(): Date {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(this.year, this.month, this.day));
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (date: Date) => void): void {
    // never being called
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
}
```

and the containing component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wp-retirement-age',
  templateUrl: './retirement-age.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './retirement-age.component.scss' ]
})
export class RetirementAgeComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      retirementDate: [ this.product.retirementDate ],
      retirementAge: [ this.product.retirementDate ]
    });

    this.retirementDateCtrl.registerOnChange((newValue) => {
      this.retirementAgeCtrl.setValue(newValue);
    });

    this.retirementAgeCtrl.registerOnChange((newValue) => {
      this.retirementDateCtrl.setValue(newValue);
    });
  }

  get retirementDateCtrl() {
    return this.form.get('retirementDate') as FormControl;
  }

  get retirementAgeCtrl() {
    return this.form.get('retirementAge') as FormControl;
  }
}
```

My component has this HTML:

```
<form class="retirement-age-form" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <div [innerHtml]="content?.wantToRetire" class="options-title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
      <wp-date-picker
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        formControlName="retirementDate"
      ></wp-date-picker>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Neither the `this.retirementDateCtrl.registerOnChange()` nor the `this.retirementAgeCtrl.registerOnChange()` are actually reaching the control's `registerOnChange()` method, so the callbacks are never being executed. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the form part of your template? Also, silly but did you import ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: I've added the HTML above, and yes I've included reactive forms :)

Comment: are you getting error?

Comment: No error, it's just that the ControlValueAccessor's registerOnChange() method is never being called. It's the FormControl's that's being called.

Comment: from a first glance it looks like you call `registerOnChange` a bit early, here is a great articly on how to register it properly:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Comment: I had a good look through the article and followed all the links to the plunkrs, but none of them demonstrate the use of registerOnChange.

Comment: You can maybe try "valueChanges" instead of "registerOnChange". It does return an observable, so you need to change your code a bit.

```this.retirementAgeCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue) => {
      this.retirementDateCtrl.setValue(newValue);
});```